How to deploy a custom model in a private service endpoint in GCP Vertex AI
I have a custom tensorflow model that I need to deploy to a private endpoint in GCP Vertex AI. The GCP documentation is lengthy and not with clear steps on how to do it. Can you please help and provide step wise details on how to deploy a custom model to a private endpoint in Vertex AI?
I am open for any type of private endpoints:
Private services access
Private Service Connect
Thanks

What "private" means for you?

Im not sure about intention of your question. I am looking for solution for deploying a custom model to a private endpoint in GCP Vertex AI.

Private can mean (old world): only my network can access it. or (new world) only the authorized account (user or service) can access it.

Only my network can access it

Do you refer to this doc? https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/using-private-endpoints There is no other option in fact. Google deploy one endpoint in its own VPC and perform a peering with yours. Then you can access it with a private IP directly through the peering. Note that this option is still in beta and not yet recommended for production. Will you access this endpoint from environment hosted outside of Google Cloud (from on prem or other cloud provider)?

I will access from within the GCP VMs

I am getting the following error when trying to crate endpoint :
Error message: "Peering range exhausted. Please refer to https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access#procedure, increase the reserved range (delete then reallocate a bigger range with the same name), and try again."

The solution is in the message!! But, because you are on Google Cloud, I strongly recommend to rely on identity (and the service account loaded from the metadata server in your compute engine) than on the network. It's not a matter of security, but a matter of simplicity (and the identity management is easier than network management, range overlap, exhaustion,....)

Can you point to some example which I use for reference? How to achieve what you suggested? I am new to Vertex AI

My requirement is simple :
I have a custom tensorflow model which I need to deploy in an endpoint in Vertex AI. I started with public endpoint but that has the issue of 1.5 MB limit on request. I have to pass image data in numpy array format.
So I am trying private endpoint to overcome the issue of limit of 1.5 MB on request.

The private and public exposition won't change the max request size. If it's your own model, you can package it in a container and host it elsewhere, on Cloud Run for instance.
